# Is it safe to have multiple threads writing to the same bool if the value is never read?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I came up with an interesting situation. I have a bool variable and then I want multiple threads to perform its own independent tasks and then mark that bool depending on the thread's result. This variable is **never** read by any of the threads and is **never** used before all writing tests have finished. Like this:

```
public bool F(){
    bool flag = false;
    Parallel.ForEach(list, element => 
    {
        bool result = // Do independent work here;
        if (result) flag = true;
    });
    return flag;
}
```

Notice how I never read flag inside my Parallel.ForEach. But what could happen is having multiple threads attempting to write true to flag (but never false). Is it safe to do this?

Comment: If the value is never read, then who cares.  Does a tree falling in an uninhabited forest make a sound?  Better to move this question to a Philosophy Q&A.

Comment: @RichardSchneider it's never read in the context of the `ForEach()` but it is afterwards when it is returned by the method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is absolutely safe to do. The only thing that could happen is multiple threads writing `true` into `flag` concurrently, so you don't know which thread would end up overriding what result, but the end result is going to be the same.

By the time you read the flag all the writing has finished, and you never attempt to write anything except `true` into `flag`. Hence, the only two situations that you could see are as follows:

- **None of the threads write anything into `flag`** - in this case the `flag` would remain `false`, or
- **One or more threads write `true` into the `flag`** - in this case the flag would be set to `true`.

If you want to avoid this situation altogether, and perhaps save some execution time, you could do this:

```
return list.AsParallel().Any(element => {
    bool result = // Do independent work here
    ...
    return result;
});
```

This code will not result in equivalent execution path, because the execution may stop early if one of the threads returns `true`. If this is not desirable, keeping your `ForEach` approach is fine, too.

Comment: What about memory visibility?  Isn't there a chance of returning `false` even when one or more threads has set `flag` to `true`?

Comment: @adv12 There's no chance of that happening, because by the time the `flag` is read every last thread will have finished execution.

Comment: What if all threads are on separate processors, and even though each thread runs to completion, the `true` values have only been written in a processor cache and haven't been flushed to main memory?  (This may just be paranoia on my part; perhaps something about Parallel.ForEach guarantees this won't happen, or maybe I just don't get threading.)

Comment: @adv12 .NET guarantees that all side effects, including writing to variables, are complete by the time the method returns.

Answer (score 3):

You're reading from `flag` when you return it.  Because there's no locking, there's no guarantee that the thread on which `F()` is called will read the most up-to-date value.  It's possible (though admittedly unlikely) that the updated value of `flag` is sitting in a processor cache that won't be flushed without a memory barrier of some kind.

Edit: in comments on @dasblinkenlight's answer, he says that ".NET guarantees that all side effects, including writing to variables, are complete by the time the method returns."  In that case this answer is wrong.  Based on his rep and my continuing uncertainty about threading, I'd be inclined to believe him, but the answers to [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27573743/correctly-loading-a-document-on-a-background-thread) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23110762/can-this-c-sharp-code-fail-because-of-a-value-in-a-register-or-cache-never-getti) I've asked here have left me pretty nervous about memory visibility.  So I don't know.  Don't take this answer with any more certainty than it deserves.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your strategy at a fundamental level. The simultaneous writes to `flag` will not be an issue strictly because of the limited semantics of how you are using it. The real question here is whether the final read of `flag` at the end of the method is safe. In this particular scenario it probably is, but only by accident. It is likely that `Parallel.For` is injecting a memory barrier without your knowledge that prevents the thread from caching the `false` value or otherwise reading a stale value. I do recommend, however, that you get in a habit of making your intentions know by explicitly placing a call to `Volatile.Read` (or any other memory barrier generating mechanism) when reading the variable.